# In highcharts.js, how to make custom ticks with an image

Tags: highcharts, axis

How would I go about and make custom image and text for an axis tick in highcharts.js? I need a normal number as label for the tick and then a small colored square image (dependant on another variable from a special array of values) displayed below the number? This is what I need to do, see image below[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an additional HTML element for rectangles and in 'load' event use color-axis to translate values into background colors.

```
const colorValues = [5, 9, 14, 15, 1, 4];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                const rectangles = document.getElementsByClassName('label-rect'),
                    colorAxis = this.colorAxis[0];

                [].forEach.call(rectangles, function(rect) {
                    rect.style.backgroundColor = colorAxis.toColor(rect.dataset.value);
                });
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            style: {
                'text-align': 'center'
            },
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.pos + '<br/>' +
                    '<span data-value="' + colorValues[this.pos] +
                    '" class="label-rect"></span>'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7146g2r3/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

Comment: Actually, I used the formatter part, from your answer, not the load method, but it worked nonetheless.